# Multiple queues causing TF to lock up

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use multiple queues for reading and batching, but this is causing TF to occasionally lock up. Here's some sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()

file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(...))
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, serialized_example = reader.read(file_queue)
keys, serialized_examples = tf.train.batch([key, serialized_example], 10)

# repeat the code snippet below multiple times, in my case 4
file_queue_i = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(...))
reader_i = tf.TextLineReader()
key_i, serialized_example_i = reader.read(file_queue_i)

initializer = tf.initialize_all_variables()

session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1, intra_op_parallelism_threads=1))
session.run(initializer)

threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=session, coord=coordinator)

session.run(keys)
```

TensorFlow occasionally locks up at the last line, when I actually try to run something. This behavior is rather hard to reproduce using the above code however. In 1000+ runs, I could only get it to hang once. In my real code, the actual reader is more complicated, and it's using TFRecords, but otherwise everything is the same. There it hangs up 2/3 of the time with 3 queues in total. With 5 queues it seemingly never runs, and with 1 queue it seemingly never hangs. This is on a Mac with 0.6. I have a different system running Ubuntu, also with 0.6, and I get the same problem (although the frequency of locking up is much higher on the Ubuntu system).

UPDATE: A more accurate estimate of how often the above code locks up is 1 in 5,000 trials.

Comment: A thread will hang if it's reading from empty queue, or pushing onto a full queue. I don't understand your snippet though, you are only reading from 2 queues, and reader_i isn't getting used anywhere

Comment: That's right, the problem occurs when I create other queues, even if I don't actively use them. I use one, but the rest are just created and are not evaluated (although naturally they will have been filled up by the queue runner). That's not the point of the code of course, but my point is that it's not necessary to evaluate the other readers to actually observe the problem. As for hanging when reading from an empty queue--shouldn't it just momentarily hang until the queue gets filled up? The hangs I'm seeing are permanent. I have to terminate.

Comment: oh, interesting....does number of threads make a difference on locking frequency?

Comment: You mean number of CPU threads or number of queues I create? I haven't tested the former, but the latter does make a difference, although not in the code snippet above. In the real reader which reads more complicated files that take a lot longer to parse, it makes a very big difference how many queues I have. I can get it to lock virtually every time if I have 3 or more queues.

Comment: I meant `inter_op_parallelism_threads`

Comment: Hmm interesting yes it does make a difference. Even in the real code, changing `inter_op_parallelism_threads` to 4 makes it hang much less frequently (no hangs in 77 trials, vs. about 1 hang per 2 trials.) Changing it to 2 threads makes it hang once every 15 trials or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by not having enough operation threads. If you have a queue runner 1 depending on work of queue runner 2, and you run them asynchronously, then you'll need at least two op threads, set through `inter_op_parallelism_threads`, to guarantee that progress is being made.

In your case, you have queue runner that's filling `batch` thread depending on `string_input_producer` queue being not empty. If the queue runner associated with `string_input_producer` queue runs first, then everything is fine. But if `batch` queue runner is scheduled first, it will get stuck in `string_input_producer.dequeue` op waiting for `string_input_producer` queue to get some filenames. Since there's only 1 thread in TensorFlow op thread pool, the `enqueue` op of `string_input_producer` will never get allocated a thread to complete (ie, to execute its `Compute` method)

Simplest solution is to have at least as many operation threads as you have simultaneous `run` calls (ie, number of queues + 1). If you really want to restrict yourself to one thread, you could preload filename queue file filenames synchronously using main thread.

```py
  coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()

  import glob
  files = glob.glob('/temp/pipeline/*')
  if FLAGS.preload_filenames:
    file_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=len(files), dtypes=tf.string)
    enqueue_val = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
    enqueue_op = file_queue.enqueue(enqueue_val)
  else:
    file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)

  reader = tf.TextLineReader()
  key, serialized_example = reader.read(file_queue)
  keys, serialized_examples = tf.train.batch([key, serialized_example], 5,
                                             capacity=10)

  initializer = tf.initialize_all_variables()

  session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                                             intra_op_parallelism_threads=1))
  print 'running initializer'
  session.run(initializer)

  if FLAGS.preload_filenames:
    print 'preloading filenames'
    for fn in files:
      session.run([enqueue_op], feed_dict={enqueue_val: fn})
      print 'size - ', session.run([file_queue.size()])
    session.run([file_queue.close()])

  print 'starting queue runners'
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=session, coord=coordinator)
  print 'about to run session'
  print session.run(keys)
```

Code above will need some encapsulation if you have more than one filenames queue. Alternatively here's a hacky work-around which should work if there's exactly `prebuffer_amount` filenames for all input_producer queues

```py
queue_runners=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS)
filename_queue_runners=[qr for qr in queue_runners if 'input_producer' in qr.name]
for qr in filename_queue_runners:
  for k in prebuffer_amount:
    sess.run(qr._enqueue_ops[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, I’m testing if increasing the thread count fixes the problem. By the above logic, shouldn’t even a single pair of `string_input_producer` and `batch` queues be prone to locking up? If it’s random which of the queues starts first, then it should lock up about 50% of the time, no? That doesn’t seem to ever happen. I tried it up to ~10,000 tries and didn’t see a single instance. But as soon as I have two pairs of queues (2 `string_input_producer` and 2 `batch` queues) it locks up in ~100 trials.

Comment: The example above locks up 50% of the time for me. So there may be something in open source thread scheduler that makes it lock up less often then expected

Comment: Ok that would make a lot more sense. Is there any way to enable multiple threads just for the queueing ops? I have code that will run in a shared environment and while I can commit 11 threads to queueing I can't do the same for the CPU intensive compute stuff.

Comment: Increasing the thread count does not solve the problem. With 10 queues (total) and 11 threads I still get a lock up after 1120 trials. It certainly _alleviates_ the problem, as 10 queues with 1 thread would rarely get past a single trial, but there must be something else going on.

Comment: what about 10 queues and 21 threads? (each queue runner can run close op in a separate thread from enqueue op)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to limit size of op threadpool only for enqueue ops, that would be a very specialized feature. I would recommend finding a way to load your filenames queues with filenames before you start reading them. There are work-arounds in answer, another work-around would be to make a custom version of "start_queue_runners", that only runs string_input_producer queues, and let them run for a bit before starting the rest of the queue runners

Comment: Even with 21 threads it is still locking up. The fact that the behavior is also so different for 2 queues (never locking vs. the 50% you're seeing with the internal TF) is making me wonder whether this is an orthogonal issue.

Comment: Hm that's a tough one, I played around a bit and couldn't find a way to reproduce this. Since problem gets worse with more python threads, the more promising workaround is to reduce number of queue runners by filling filename queues manually

Comment: Could it be that the arithmetic for number of threads needed is wrong? Eventually I upped it to 40 threads and it hasn't failed since, despite trying over 10,000 times. With 21 threads it failed in ~500 trials. Regardless, I agree that filling filename queues manually is the way to go.

Comment: If increasing size of op threadpool fixes things, this suggests that at some point 21 compute threads were tied up in blocking operations. So for instance if you had 21 reader.read nodes all trying to access an empty filenames queue, then a single run call would lock up 21 compute threads. If you had 2 independent run calls, each triggering 21 reader.read nodes, then you'd lock up 42 compute threads

Comment: The trick of manually enqueuing the file names before starting the threads seems to work pretty well. One thing to note though is that `queue_runner` doesn't have a `name` attribute, but I can grab it from `enqueue_ops`.

Comment: "name" property was added on Dec 14, maybe it's only in head atm

Comment: Seems like other people are noticing this issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/929

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I commented that issue with a link to the discussion here.

Comment: BTW, there's been a recent change to address deadlocking issue, maybe update your TF version -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772292/tensorflow-reading-a-csv-file-hangs-forever

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.