# TensorFlow: Reading a CSV file hangs forever

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I've followed the tutorial and the [csv example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#csv-files) shown there doesn't seem to work. It gets stuck forever...

Here's the code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.csv", "file1.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.pack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

I'm using Tensorflow 0.7.1 and Python3.

What am I doing wrong?

My files have only this row:

```
5,4,3,2,1
```

Comment: This exact code is working for me (in both TF 0.6.0 and 0.7.1, with Python 2.7 and 3.4). Can you try adding `print(example, label)` after the `sess.run()` call to determine if it's making any progress?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just hangs on the run step. I'm on Python 3.4.Suppose it has some problem reading the files (permissions, not found, etc), then it should throw an error, right?

Comment: Yes, when I try it from a different directory (so that the files won't be found) it terminates with a `NotFoundError`. Is there anything strange about the files (like are they on a remote filesystem) that could cause them to block on reading?

Comment: Weird, I don't get errors when the file is not accessible! I have tf on a virtual machine and my code shared via shared folders and so in order to check for i/o problems I copied everything into other directory outside the share, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Done a snippet in python only that prints the file's first line and it works fine. So tf shouldn't have problems opening/reading the file. f = open('file0.csv', 'r')
print(f.readline())
f.close()

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it should be fine. Could it be a path issue (inconsistency between Python and C++)? Try replacing the filenames with absolute paths to see if that helps….

Comment: Tried that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure how to reconstruct the problem. Perhaps running the script under `strace` would provide some clues (you might see it hanging in a `read()` call for example).

Comment: When I run it with python3 -m trace --listfuncs readcsv.py > out.txt I get an error: 
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x7fc6a00023b0 Compute status: Cancelled: Enqueue operation was cancelled
  [[Node: input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueMany[Tcomponents=[DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer, input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:286] Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt

and the out.txt repeats this 1200 times:

0
[5 4 3 2] 1

Comment: Is that the only error? Typically this is a symptom of an earlier error, which causes the coordinator to close the queue and everything pending on it then fails noisily. If you code post all of `out.txt` as a [gist](https://gist.github.com) I can take a look.

Comment: Yes, that's the only error. I've sent you the --listfuncs log on [gist](https://gist.github.com/oliveirabc/838010d46d6a35b5d2b8). When using the listfuncs option: reads the file, throws the error and then prints the trace info. It looks like it reaches a deadlock when running normally but is able to read the file in trace!

Comment: I think I found the way to reconstruct the problem. The virtualbox machine had 1 processor only, as soon as I changed it to have 2 processors the problem was over.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this! I posted an answer that explains the problem you were seeing.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your persistence on trying to debug this. It turns out that you were running into a bug that was fixed in [a recent commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/841656c9fd84902733e2ee13ac4dd9020a5b6361), but the fix hasn't made it into a release yet. There are two possible fixes (other than [acquiring more processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772292/cant-read-csv-with-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment59255028_35772292)):

1. Upgrade to the [nightly binary release](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation) or [install from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources), to get the fix.
2. In your Python program, add the following to the [session creation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.__init__):

   ```
   config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=2)
   with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
     # ...
   ```

The reason for the issue is that TensorFlow uses a bounded threadpool for dispatching ops, and (until the fix) the reader op could block, which would lead to deadlock if another op had to run before the reader could complete (for example because of a producer-consumer relationship). The fix addresses this by running the reader asynchronously.

Comment: 1 - I'll try that later on
2 - It worked, no problem after adding that bit

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may save some people grief to note in TensorFlow 0.10 the both the amendment from [Bruno Oliveira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6012841/bruno-oliveira) and formatting is required in Python 3.0, not seen this working in Python 2.x even with correct 2.x print syntax.

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["./iris.data"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32),   # Column 0
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32),   # Column 1
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32),   # Column 2
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32),
              tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string)] 
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.pack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=2)
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
# Start populating the filename queue.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
        example, label = sess.run([features, col5])
        print(example, label)

   coord.request_stop()
   coord.join(threads)
```