# Reading CSV files with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to read a tensor from a CSV file and print it. I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772292/tensorflow-reading-a-csv-file-hangs-forever), but the script still hangs. data.csv consists of one line:

```
1.5,2.5
```

Here's the code that reads it:

```
datafile = tf.train.string_input_producer([os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data.csv")])
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, value = reader.read(datafile)
record_defaults = [[1], [1]]
col1, col2 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
result = tf.stack([col1, col2])
config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=2)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this part from the answer you quoted. If you don't add the coordinator and start the queue runners, the queue will never be enqueued and the session will hang, waiting for an element to be enqueued.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I added the config line because another post recommended it.